# General process for compensating a complex system in the time domain

Tags: transfer-function, compensation

Say one has a system with feedback wrapping around some "complicated" system (more complicated than the traditional examples given):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqwXmM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

\$A1\$ is a real op amp but with non-trivial (more than one pole) and not analytically known transfer function.   \$A2\$ is a difference amplifier / level shifter and PMOS output stage.  The transfer function for \$A2\$ is also unknown. \$B2\$ is the compensation loop around the first op amp, and B1 is the global feedback loop that sets the global gain.

I understand the concept of how to find B2 and B1 in the frequency domain, however that kind of analysis isn't always possible: I don't have access to a network analyzer, and [LT Spice doesn't always give the right AC analysis transfer function](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/234410/ltspice-divergence-between-ac-analysis-and-transient-analysis-for-low-frequency).

How do I go about designing B2, and modifying B1 in order to compensate this system in the time domain?

Comment: You can always look at the overshoot and try and compensate the network by experimentation with adding\subtracting capacatance (or inductance) to try and change the characteristic of the loop. Please be more specific, what op amp? What speed?

Comment: I'm looking for general strategies, not specific answers to MY problem.  Do you know of a more rigorous extension to your idea?

Comment: Thats kind of my point, EE.SE discourages non-specific questions as they only generate discussion and not answers. "We feel the best Electronics Design questions have a schematic, links to pertinent datasheets or some source code in them, but if your question generally covers 
    a specific electronics design problem
    the theory and simulation of electromagnetic forces" It would be best to make this question more specific or it may be closed as being "too broad" meaning there is no real way to answer the question without further information. Questions like these generate lots of comments

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is a specific question.  I am looking for a "rigorous" method for designing a compensation network for non-trivial problems in the time domain.  An answer that is "experiment until you get the right answer" is not an acceptable answer.  An answer with a specific set of steps, or a specific heuristic IS an acceptable answer.  If you would like I can name the variables that I think are relevant:  \$A_{A1 ol}\$, \$A_{A2 ol}\$, \$GBW_{A1}\$, etc., but I'm not necessarily sure which ones they are.

Comment: How about this: Please ask a question in your post, you have defined your problem and that part looks great. But there also needs to be a question so people can answer it.

Comment: @laptop2d: I have changed the last paragraph to make clear the question I am asking.  I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Looks great, are there any assumptions you can make about the inner loop? Is it compensated? Without knowing something about the inner loop there is no way you can compensate the outer loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44812/discussion-between-andrew-spott-and-laptop2d).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the first questions you probably need to ask yourself is: do I want to maximize the possible bandwidth of the system or do I just need to make it stable?

One way I have dealt with this issue is to make sure that the unity gain bandwidth of the A1/B2 loop is much higher (I use 10x as a rule of thumb but it could be lower) than the desired bandwidth of the outer loop. If that isn't possible due to bandwidth limitations of A2/B1 then you are going to have a really hard time compensating the system.

Once the inner loop is compensated at an acceptable bandwidth, then you can focus on the outer loop. In this case it helps (but not required) to target an outer loop unity gain bandwidth to be at a point where the inner loop is close to single pole roll-off. This makes it easy(er) to calculate where to put your dominant pole to compensate for ringing/settling-time etc.

Without more detail in the question it's hard for me to give more heuristics than this. Hope it helps.

Comment: A1 is a unity gain stable op amp, and is compensated on its own.  Only when the outer loop is added (and the time delay caused by A2), do I run into issues with compensation.

Comment: Time delay from A2 would only help stability right? I would say that limiting the outer loop bandwidth until the system is stable would be a starting point

Comment: Time delay from A2 is equivalent to a phase delay.  Too much phase delay is pretty much my entire problem... :).  Now that I am thinking about it, without a feedback loop around A1, there isn't any stability guarantees, I'll have to go back and make sure that it has SOME feedback to guarantee stability...

Comment: You are correct. What I meant to say was that if A2 is adding too much phase delay you can use B1 to limit the bandwidth of the outer loop so that the unity gain crossover point happens before you lose all your phase margin

Comment: Yea.  Unfortunately, the answer to your first question that you are asking is "yes, i want to maximize the possible bandwidth of the system" :).

Comment: Good. If you know the delay of A2 you can calculate how much phase you are losing there. So I would start by making the system stable first. You can learn quite a bit of information from the time-domain behavior of the signal. Once you have your outer-loop stable, then you can gradually increase the bandwidth until things look bad. At that point, if the bandwidth is close to the theoretical limit imposed by A2 then that's probably as fast as you can go. Otherwise, you may be able to go faster by extending the A1/B2 loop bandwidth

Answer (score 1):

Feedback loops can be simplified as such, using your notation: $$ H_{inner}(s)= [A_1(s)/(1+A_1(s)*B_2(s))] $$

The new inner loop can be multiplied by \$ A_3(s) \$

$$H_{innertotal}(s)= \frac{A_1(s)}{(1+A_1(s)*B_2(s))]*A_2(s)} $$

The ending transfer function would look like this

$$ H_{total}(s)= \frac{H_{innertotal}(s)}{(1+H_{innertotal}(s)*B_1(s))} $$ or $$H_{total}(s)=\frac{\frac{A_1(s)}{(1+A_1(s)*B_2(s))}*A_2(s)}{\frac{A_1(s)}{(1+A_1(s)*B_2(s))}*A_2(s)*B_1(s))}$$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvCK2q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This doesn't address the OP question though because "A1 is a real op amp but with non-trivial (more than one pole) and not analytically known transfer function. A2 is a difference amplifier / level shifter and PMOS output stage. The transfer function for A2A2 is also unknown."

Comment: I know, when I started the answer that information was not there